# How to define a divergence-free vector or a traceless tensor in xAct?

Tags: xact

I'm trying to implement a Friedmann-Lemaître-Robertson-Walker metric + a perturbation in a scalar-vector-tensor split in mathematica, using xAct. The S-V-T decomposition comes with some rules for the vector and tensor parts, i.e. the vector is transverse and divergence-free and the tensor is transverse and traceless. How can I implement this?

**Divergence-free Vector**

Can I make a rule, before I set a metric and have the corresponding covariant derivative? I need to set it before, because it is part of the metric...

Doing it later gives me

```
DFBRule =   MakeRule[{cd[a][Bv[-a]], 0}, PatternIndices -> All, 
   MetricOn -> All];
** MakeRule: Potential problems moving indices on the LHS.
   Rules {1,1} have been declared as UpValues for Bv.
```

**Traceless Tensor**

`DefTensor[Ct[a, b], M]` knows only the argument `symmetric`, but not traceless. I thought, maybe, I could redefine it like

```
Ct[a,b]=MakeTraceless[Ct[a,b]]
```

But this only throws a couple of errors:

```
First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element.
ToCanonical::noident: Unknown expression not canonicalized: First[{}][-a,-b] .
ToCanonical::noident: Unknown expression not canonicalized: First[{}][-a,-b] .
ChangeFreeIndices::error: Inconsistent number of free indices.
Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Null] returned to top level.
```

I also thought about

```
TFRule = MakeRule[{Ct[a, -a], 0}, PatternIndices -> All, 
   MetricOn -> All];
AutomaticRules[Ct, TFRule];
```

but I maybe there is a more direct approach to define vectors and tensors right away as divergence-free or trace-free. How can it be done? Thank you very much in advance for your reply!